# docker cant find file in parent folder?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a problem where docker build can't find my files and I've tried many folder references but I cant get my head around the folder structure. No matter what its wrong.

This is my project (slimmed down) structure:

[image]

This is my docker file:

```
# pull official base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add app csprojfiles
COPY ./myapi.sln .
```

and this is the error:

```
failed to compute cache key: "/myapi.sln" not found: not found
```

I've tried `COPY ../myapi.sln .` and simply `myapi.sln` but its not found no matter what. Im running command `docker build web.api/` from the parent myapi folder in command prompt.

Comment: You must provider a "build context" that includes the required files. Have you tried `docker build myapi` (or whatever folder is "above" `web.api`) and adjusting the relative paths in the Dockerfile? Also see [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description) docs for more about build context.

Comment: There is no Dockerfile in myapi parent folder, its one located in api folder named api. I have to target the Dockerfile to build @tentative

Comment: You can also provide the path the the Dockerfile with `docker build -f ./path/to/Dockerfile ./path/to/context`

Answer (score 3):

Your path is wrong. By writing `COPY ./myapi.sln .` you assume that `myapi.sln` is in the same folder than the Dockerfile which is not the case.

Best practice is to put the Dockerfile at the root of your project so you can easily access all your files.

In anyway, you can't access a parent directory with absolute or relative path.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something/something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

Comment: Okey, but then I have to have at the root... and with multiple projects like web (frontend), api and such Ill have to use Dockerfile.web, Dockerfile.api and such to create the different Dockerfiles?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, but if you have different Dockerfile for different project, you can just put each project in a different directory, and put the Dockerfile related to this project at the root of his directory.

In your case, you should put the ```myapi.snl``` in the ```web.api``` so it will be accessible by the Dockerfile inside of the ```web.api``` directory. 

Now if you have a file that you need to use for 2 different Dockerfile, you can put one of the Dockerfile at the root of the whole project so it will be able to access more than one project/directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using docker-compose.

Let's assume we have the following directory structure:

```
├───Project
│   ├───docker
│   │   └───frontend.dockerfile
│   └───frontend-app
│       ├───index.html
│       └───package.json
└───────docker-compose.yml
```

In the `frontend.dockerfile`, we use the node:16 base image, set the working directory to /app, and copy the package.json file to the working directory. We then run npm install to install the dependencies and copy the application files to the working directory. Finally, we set the command to npm start.

frontend.dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./frontend-app/package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY /frontend-app .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

In the `docker-compose.yml` file, we define a service called frontend that uses the frontend.dockerfile for building. We map port 3000 from the container to port 3000 on the host and mount the frontend-app directory as a volume. We set the command to npm run install to install the dependencies.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/frontend.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend-app:/app
    command: npm run install
```

In the build section of the frontend service, we specify the path to the frontend.dockerfile and set the context to the root of the project directory.